# Centering an element on the current Viewport in a Scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I want to display a dot, which is always in the physical center of my device, even when I scroll the content around it, which is in a scrollview. This is my current code, but the dot is missing here, because I don't know where to place it. The scrollposition is only set via code, so it wouldn't be a problem, if the centered element blocks the scrollview.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
android:gravity="center">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/vertsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horisv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/map" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Solution :

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:deviceIds="wear_square">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/vertsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horisv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/map" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_black_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why you couldn't draw this point from onDraw() instead of building confusing layout from xml?

Comment: Want you to  only center your image ? please explain something.

Comment: The easiest way is to place your dot out of scrollview. In this case you will be able align as you need.

Comment: @StasLelyuk I tried to place it outside, but I guess it is then below my scrollview, since I couldn't see the image.

Comment: I didn't think about the onDraw() solution, I will read into that

Comment: @TobiasW Want you to only center your image ? please explain something.

Comment: Yes just center the image and it shouldn't move with the scrollview

Comment: If you want to place view on the top of hierarchy - it should be below everything else in your layout. In you case you also should use FrameLayout/RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as a top parent container.

Comment: Do you want to provide an answer? I got it solved now, but I want to give you the opportunity to provide a solution to get the points :) And yeah I did it like you said simply use a relative layout and wrapped the scrollstuff in a linearlayout

Comment: Then you need to put your imageview just below NestedScrollView. That's it

Comment: @StasLelyuk I did that before I asked the question, but it didn't work, but it works now with a relativelayout around everything.

Comment: Great! I've finally added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your dot below anything else in your layout. Also you should use FrameLayout/RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as a top parent container.